# HTTP Posting large string results in request timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, http

My desktop application is HTTP posting data to my Apache server (interacting with my PHP script). I am posting alot of data (the contents of a file that is 800kb in size).

When I send the HTTP post request it times out with the below Windows error:

> ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT The request has timed out

But if I send smaller files then everything is fine and my PHP script handles the post request. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix this?

My website is WordPress and I have changed my `php.ini`, `php5.ini` and `.user.ini` to all have the following text but it still fails for large files.

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

**Edit**: After inspecting using `phpinfo();` (should max_execution_time have an S on the end (for seconds?):

- max_execution_time    10
- memory_limit  128M
- post_max_size 128M
- upload_max_filesize   128M
- max_input_nesting_level   64
- max_input_time    10
- max_input_vars    1000

C++ code:

```
TCHAR hdrs[] = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
LPSTR accept[2] = { "*/*", NULL };

HINTERNET hConnect = NULL, hSession = NULL, hRequest = NULL;
DWORD len = postData.length() * 2;
tstring formattedPostData(len, ' ');
InternetCanonicalizeUrl(postData.c_str(), &formattedPostData[0], &len, ICU_BROWSER_MODE);
std::replace(formattedPostData.begin(), formattedPostData.end(), '=', '~');
tstring authData = _T("usage=") + formattedPostData + _T("&auth=") + authToken;

hSession = InternetOpen(_T("uploader"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (!hSession) {
    output(_T("InternetOpen failed: %s\n"), getLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    res = S_UNDEFINED_ERROR.state;
    goto Cleanup;
}

hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, domain.c_str(),
    INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
if (!hConnect) {
    output(_T("InternetConnect failed: %s\n"), getLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    res = S_UNDEFINED_ERROR.state;
    goto Cleanup;
}

hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("POST"),
    domainScript.c_str(), NULL, NULL, (LPCWSTR*)&accept, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 1);
if (!hRequest) {
    output(_T("HttpOpenRequest failed: %s\n"), getLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    res = S_UNDEFINED_ERROR.state;
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Error occurs here
output(_T("Post: %s\n"), authData.c_str());
if (!HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, -1, (LPVOID)authData.c_str(), authData.size() * sizeof(TCHAR))) {
    // Error is 12002: timeout
    output(_T("HttpSendRequest failed: %d.\n"), GetLastError());
    res = S_UNDEFINED_ERROR.state;

    char responseText[1024]; 
    DWORD responseTextSize = sizeof(responseText);

    output(_T("Res: %d\n"), HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, &responseText, &responseTextSize, NULL));
    output(_T("Response: %s\n"), responseText);

    goto Cleanup;
}
```

Comment: check error log and let me know.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/de/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)

Comment: @SachinG. I've checked the error log and there's no entry for today.

Comment: what is your max_execution_time in php.ini?

Comment: @SachinG. its 10, see my edit that displays some phpinfo() attribs

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the script timeout?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Also are you posting files or chunks of text copy'n'pasted into a textarea or the like?

Comment: my desktop application is posting the file contents as one long string. For eg; `fileContents=abc....&auth=abc`

Comment: As a http post or get? Also the string you're sending are there any weird characters in there?

Comment: its a post and it is urlencoded but I also have to replace the files `=` characters with `~` characters to not conflict with post format

Comment: ok cool - are you using a form to send the data up? have you set the enctype? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp Have you got an example of some code we could look at.

Comment: also when updating the .ini files did you restart the http server?

Comment: Its a GoDaddy shared server, how would I/can I restart it?

Comment: hmm not sure - perhaps it will take affect straight away. Create a page with the following in to see if your ini updates are in affect.

<?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: also if you setup a local server do you get the same issue?

Comment: https://au.godaddy.com/help/phpiniuserini-changes-not-taking-effect-5647

Comment: ok, thanks for doing the phpinfo bits. The max_execution_time and max_input_time are in seconds and dont need an 's' on the end. But they are a little low - try upping them to 30 or 60 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: also have you tried changing the header to multipart/form-data instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this issue with **cpanel and cloudflare** using **php and jquery**
when I am making POST request using Jquery and pass urls and files names data after waiting too many minutes it give timeout error.
I debug and there is no complex operation on backend that take much time

> if i make get request with same url it works fine

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("regNo" , jsonObj.regNo);
form.append("email" , jsonObj.email);
form.append("phone" , jsonObj.phone);
form.append("file" , jsonObj.file);
form.append("url" , obj);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
    data: form,
    success: function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

at last I add enctype: 'multipart/form-data', to jquery ajax code and it works fine

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    processData:false,
    contentType:false, 
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: form,
    success: function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```